# How to build pjsip on windows

Tags: windows, voip, pjsip, sdl-2

I am going to build pjsip on window7,and I almost be ready to compile the project,but something confused me is one of the steps show in this page:[link](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows)

It is said about SDL2,describe is here:
SDL sources comes with VS project settings, under VisualC sub-directory

So,what should I do indict by the description?

Another question,should I build SDL2 from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build SDL only if you want to compile PJSIP with video enabled. 
It is used for rendering only. If you want you can build it from source.

Another option for rendering is DirectShow but it's broken for ages. 
I developed a renderer driver for PJSIP to render to a bitmap and than I render this bitmap in C#. It's easier and works fast.

Also for video you will need ffmpeg at least for codecs.
My opinion: start without video. It's not easy to make it work and might be you won't need it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:)This is my job task to build pjsip with vedio support,so I should just compile SDL and add its include/ and lib/ to pjsua project,right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this is a long way with a lot of bugs inside PJSIP.

The second question - how to integrate video windows to your app. I  suggest you stick to bitmap rendering. It's easier to understand and manage. And can be rendered anywhere.

SDL can render only to Hwnd. And if you're developing for WPF you don't have Hwnd. Feel free to ask if you need something.

Comment: @Thanks,now I am using visual studio to build pjsua,but error occurs:e:\pj\mingw\include\_mingw.h(51) : fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: You must use a GNU Compiler.I google it,but just found no answer.

Comment: I resolve the GNU compiler problem myself,I set unnecessary include file in vs2008.